# How to get Principal Component Data in PAM in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, cluster-analysis, pca, ggfortify

I create a graph using *autoplot* function using mtcars data and get graph like this

[image]

here my code:

```
library(cluster)
library(NbClust)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfortify)
x <- mtcars
number.cluster <- NbClust(x, distance = "euclidean", min.nc = 1, max.nc = 5, method = "complete", index = "ch")
best.cluster <- as.numeric(number.cluster$Best.nc[1])
x.pam <- pam(x, best.cluster)
autoplot(x.pam, data = x, frame = T) + ggtitle("PAM MTCARS")
```

my question is how do i get PC1 & PC2 data Coordinate based on this graph?
thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "get PC1 & PC2 data Coordinate"?

Comment: Hi, if you look at the graph, you'll see PC1 & PC2. I think this graph is plotted by PC1 & PC2 Data, but i don't know how to extract it..

Comment: Getting an error about `pam` not found. You should a) figure out which package has pam and add a `library` call, and b) look at the help page for `pam` and see if the data is in one of the list components of `x.pam`

Comment: @42-, pam is from `cluster` package

Comment: Modifications of the code in questions should be applied with SO [edit] features.

Comment: thank you, i think miss one library, yes it's from Cluster Library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `layer_data()` to get the data used for a ggplot object:

```
p <- autoplot(x.pam, data = x, frame = T) + ggtitle("PAM MTCARS")
layer_data(p, 1L) # coordinates of all points
layer_data(p, 2L) # coordinates of points that contribute to polygons
```

Answer (score 2):

Your entire process is flawed. First you use complete linkage to estimate the number of clusters; but rather than using the "best" clustering found you then cluster again with PAM instead.
You use Euclidean distance, but in Euclidean space k-means will usually work better than PAM - PAM shines when you don't have Euclidean geometry and *cannot* use k-means.

And then you want to use this PCA plot, which is *heavily distorted* (almost the entire variance is in the first component, the y axis is visualizing pretty much random deviation). Just use PCA if you want these coordinates, not reconstruct this from the plot.

Comment: Wow thank you for your advice, i just wanna construct it with my real data. MTCARS only for example. But your advice is cool. I'm working on it..
Thanks for it